# Python Selenium Ubuntu Server Memory Crash Issues

Tags: python, selenium, out-of-memory, ubuntu-16.04

I have written some Python scripts based on Selenium to pull data from a CRM website every day based on some brands. I have deployed these scripts to run on an EC2 Ubuntu Server. They run every day for each brand and grab the data and upload it on spreadsheets.

However, the problem here is that while a daily run works out fine, on a specific few fixed dates, the script has to run for all the previous dates of the month for every brand. So due to this, I have observed that it takes up too much memory and eventually the memory gets full and I lose access to the EC2 instance. At this stage I have to STOP and START the instance again.

While some of the functions are irrelevant, I'm sharing the main script which handles browsers here.

```
import sys
# sys.setdefaultencoding() does not exist, here!
reload(sys)  # Reload does the trick!
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')


import time
from functools import wraps

PROF_DATA = {}

def profile(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def with_profiling(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.time()

        ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)

        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time

        if fn.__name__ not in PROF_DATA:
            PROF_DATA[fn.__name__] = [0, []]
        PROF_DATA[fn.__name__][0] += 1
        PROF_DATA[fn.__name__][1].append(elapsed_time)

        return ret

    return with_profiling

def print_prof_data():
    for fname, data in PROF_DATA.items():
        max_time = max(data[1])
        avg_time = sum(data[1]) / len(data[1])
        print ("Function %s called %d times. " % (fname, data[0]),)
        print ('Execution time max: %.3f, average: %.3f' % (max_time, avg_time))

def clear_prof_data():
    global PROF_DATA
    PROF_DATA = {}

@profile
def main(driver, wait, month, day, year):
    i = 0
    while i<3:
        try:
            print('Leads')
            driver.delete_all_cookies()
            pullLeads(driver,wait, month, day, year)
            i = 0
            break
        except Exception as e:
            driver.refresh()
            if "index" in str(e):
                break
            print(e)
            i = i + 1
            pass
    i = 0
    while i<3:
        try:
            print('Appointments')
            driver.delete_all_cookies()
            pullAppointments(driver, wait,month, day, year)
            i = 0
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            driver.refresh()
            i = i + 1
            pass
    i = 0
    while i<3:
        try:
            print('Meetings')
            driver.delete_all_cookies()
            pullMeetings(driver, wait, month, day, year)
            i = 0
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            driver.refresh()
            i = i + 1
            pass
    i = 0
    while i<3:
        try:
            print('Sold')
            driver.delete_all_cookies()
            pullSold(driver, wait, month, day, year)
            i = 0
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            driver.refresh()

            i = i + 1
            pass

today = datetime.today().day
yesterday = datetime.today() - timedelta(days = 1)
year = yesterday.strftime('%Y')
month = yesterday.strftime('%m')
day = yesterday.strftime('%d')
daysToRestart = [4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 31]
driver, wait = start_browser()

import time

start = time.time()


print(day,month,year)
if today in daysToRestart:
    print('Loop initiated!')
    day = 1
    while(day < today):
        print('Date: '+str(day))
        main(driver, wait, month, day, year)
        day = day + 1
else:
    main(driver, wait, month, day, year)

driver.quit()

end = time.time()
print('Total time taken (minutes): ')
print((end - start)/60.0)
```

And the relevant **start_browser** function is as follows:

```
def start_browser():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    driver.set_page_load_timeout("30")
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    return driver, wait
```

I am using Python2 with Firefox as the browser in its "headless" state owing to the server constraint.

How do I fix this memory crash issue?

Keep in mind that it has to run for many dates and that there are **Eight** such scripts which will eventually run in parallel, but which will be scheduled at different times in the **crontab**.

**PS:** I have tried running all the dates in the same browser but this doesn't fix the issue. I am spawning a new browser per date only to ensure that I am calling driver.close() and driver.quit() properly.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: There is no error message, Just server crashing due to memory full.

Comment: first you could test code on local computer - and see how much memory it uses and if it really use only one browser for all pages/dates.

Comment: I have actually. Goes through fine at local computer. Though tested it on Windows as opposed to Ubuntu server with no GUI.